# Encryption algorithm clarification

Tags: string, algorithm, math, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to create  and encryptor and parser for my personal project.
Suppose I encrypt latin alphabet as follows:

a = a;
b = ab;
c = aab;
....
z = a...ab

In this case the string "aaab" can be decrypted in multiple ways:
ac, aab

But if I encrypt the alhabet as follows:

a = a;
b = ab;
c = abb;
....
z = a...bb

In this case any string can be decrypted in one and only unique way.

Is there an algorithm or theorem that describes this behavior? Will this be a correct encryption or for a very long strings I can somehow gain ambiguity.

Comment: It's probably a better fit for [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You're referring to properties of classical ciphers more than modern encryption.  Your question is more on topic on the cryptography site.  Modern encryption is *way* past constructs like that.

Comment: thanks @harold, can you please formulate an answer please

Comment: "Will this be a correct encryption": besides the fact that it is unacceptably non-compact, this "encryption" is cracked in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [uniquely decodable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code#Uniquely_decodable_codes) codes.

One example of uniquely decodable codes are [prefix-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) codes. Meaning, there are no two characters `A` and `B` such that `encode(A)` is a prefix of `encode(B)`. That is relatively easy to check.

If your code is prefix-free, it can be easily decoded: you just take the only prefix of the encoded string which corresponds to some character. Say, [Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) is a popular example of prefix-free code used for compression.

The converse is not true, though, as your second code is not prefix-free, but is still uniquely decodable. There are some algorithms to check whether code is uniquely decodable (e.g. [in this presentation](http://www.eem.anadolu.edu.tr/ongerek/EEM562/icerik/decodable.pdf)), but I'm not aware of any beautiful reformulation. One requirement for the code to be uniquely decodable is [Kraft–McMillan inequalily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%27s_inequality), but it can hold for non-uniquely decodable codes as well (e.g. your first code).

Comment: but here, a is a prefix for ab, ab is a prefix for abb. ist it?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan that's right: `a, ab, abb, ...` code is not prefix-free, but it's still uniquely decodable.

Comment: so if i change a = a to a = b in first example, it will be prefix free and uniquely construable?